# Scheme: Counting types using recursion

Tags: recursion, racket, accumulator

Structure Definition:

```
(define-struct movie (title genre stars))
;; title is a nonempty string
;; genre is a nonempty string
;; stars us a list of nonempty strings
```

I am trying to write a scheme function that consumes a list of movies and produces the genre that occurs most often.

So far, I have the following:

```
(define (popular-gnere movies)
(local
[(define acc movies genre)
(cond
[(empty? movies) genre]
[(equal? genre (movie-genre (first movies)))
(acc (rest movies genre)))
```

I'm stuck as to how I can keep count of how many times a specific genre has appeared in a given list of movies.
I understand that accumulated recursion in this case would be most efficient but am having trouble completing my accumulator.

Comment: -1 for formatting that makes it so readers can't tell whether the code is syntactically correct, let alone whether it does what it's supposed to, or what might not be right about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you fix your parentheses problem and indent the code properly. Press <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. Where the identation is wrong you probably have missing parentheses. Press <kbd>Run</kbd> to evaluate and you'd get proper error messages. When you have something that doesn't produce errors, update this question.

The answer your question you add more parameters to your local procedures than the global. That way you hae a parameter that can hold a count that you increase when you find the search element in the current element.eg.

```
(define (length lst)
  (define (length-aux lst cnt)
    (if (null? lst)
        cnt
        (length-aux (cdr lst) (add1 cnt))))
  (length-aux lst 0))
```

Or better with named `let`

```
(define (length lst)
  (let length-aux ((lst lst) (cnt 0))
    (if (null? lst)
        cnt
        (length-aux (cdr lst) (add1 cnt)))))
```

**EDIT**

I recommend having at least 4 helper procedures that takes each their part of a problem. (Less if you make use racket's own `remove`, `count`, and `argmax`). Note that there are probably many other ways to solve this but this is how I would have solved it without a hash table.

Since you are only interested in genre the first thing to imagine is  that you can do `(map movie-genre lst)` so that you get a list of genres to work with in your main helper.

In your main helper you can build up a list of cons having genre and count. To do that you use a helper `count` that  `(count 'c '(a b c d c c a) 0) ==> 3` and you just take the first genre and count the list for those as the first accumulated value, then process the result of `(remove 'c '(a b c d c c a) '()) ==> (a d b a)` on the rest of the list. 
When processing is done you have in your accumulator `((a . 4) (b . 6) ...)` and you need a helper `(max-genre 'a 4 '((b . 6) (c . 20) (d . 10))) ; ==> c`

The main helper would look something like this:

```
(define (aux lst acc)
  (if (null? lst) 
      (max-genre (caar acc) (cdar acc) (cdr acc))
      (aux (remove (car lst) lst '())
           (cons (cons (car lst) (count (car lst) lst 0)) acc))))
```

Now you could do it a lot simpler with a [hash table](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html) in one pass. You'd still have to have `max-genre`/`argmax` after reading all elements once.

Comment: To make it easier to implement this, would you recommend having two accumulator functions ... one to count number of types, and another that determines which one occurs the most?

Comment: @Guest It's not a beginner problem but it can easily be reduced to very simple operations. I've added some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to settle on a key-value datatype. You could use association lists, but hash tables are a more efficient choice.

Let's start with a short list:

```scm
(define-struct movie (title genre stars))
(define films
  (list
   (make-movie "Godfater" "Crime" '("Marlon Brando" "Al Pacino"))
   (make-movie "Rambo" "Thriller" '("Sylvester Stallone"))
   (make-movie "Silence of the Lambs" "Crime" '("Jodie Foster" "Anthony Hopkins"))))
```

and create an empty hash table

```scm
(define h (make-hash))
```

Now we process every film, updating the hash table as we go:

```scm
> (for-each (lambda (e) (hash-update! h e add1 0)) (map movie-genre films))
> h
'#hash(("Thriller" . 1) ("Crime" . 2))
```

Now we need to find the highest count:

```scm
> (hash-values h)
'(1 2)
> (define most (foldl (lambda (e r) (if (> e r) e r)) 0 (hash-values h)))
> most
2
```

So 2 is our highest count. Now we create a list of all genres with count 2:

```scm
> (hash->list h)
'(("Thriller" . 1) ("Crime" . 2))
> (foldl
   (lambda (e r)  (if (= (cdr e) most) (cons (car e) r) r))
   null
   (hash->list h))
'("Crime")
```

Putting it all together:

```scm
(define (count-by-genre lst)
  (define h (make-hash))
  (for-each (lambda (e) (hash-update! h e add1 0)) (map movie-genre lst))
  (define most (foldl (lambda (e r) (if (> e r) e r)) 0 (hash-values h)))
  (foldl
   (lambda (e r)  (if (= (cdr e) most) (cons (car e) r) r))
   null
   (hash->list h)))
```

But this is quite inefficient, for several reasons:

1. after updating the hash table, we have to re-iterate over it, create a list and then apply `foldl` just to find the highest value, whereas we could have just kept note of it while updating the hash table
2. then again we create a full list (`hash->list`) and a final result list using `foldl`.

Lots of consing and stuff. An alternative, more efficient version using Racket-specific `for` constructs, could be:

```scm
(define (count-by-genre lst)
  (define h (make-hash))
  (define most
    (for/fold ((highest 0)) ((e (in-list (map movie-genre lst))))
      (define new (add1 (hash-ref h e 0)))
      (hash-set! h e new)
      (max highest new)))
  (for/fold ((res null)) (((k v) (in-hash h)))
    (if (= v most) (cons k res) res)))
```